# Apache 2.4 (52) debugging, several stuck apache2 -k start at 99%-ish CPU. strace stuck on FUTEX

Tags: apache, http, ubuntu, https

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
3023 www-data  20   0  262216  19280   8848 R  93.8   0.2   3:47.05 /usr/sbin/apach
```

**Kernel release: 5.15.0-1002-aws**

There are several that get stuck this way. Most do not return anything using strace -p . I've tried the root or earliest pid, but I can't find the culprit. I've tried:

```
rm /dev/random 
mknod -m 644 /dev/random c 1 9
```

No luck.

Sometimes I get:

```
db1:/root# screen
db1:/root# strace -p 3015
strace: Process 3015 attached
futex(0x7f75134a7000, FUTEX_LOCK_PI, NULL^Cstrace: Process 3015 detached
 <detached ...>
```

The root pid (lowest pid) says this:

```
db1:/var/log/apache2# strace -p 3002
strace: Process 3002 attached
pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=765119225}, NULL) = 0 (Timeout)
wait4(-1, 0x7ffdd64a2f64, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0
times({tms_utime=3 /* 0.03 s */, tms_stime=4 /* 0.04 s */, tms_cutime=0, tms_cstime=0}) = 1718048747
pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, NULL) = 0 (Timeout)
wait4(-1, 0x7ffdd64a2f64, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0
```

I've updated, rebooted, it is a new installation of Ubuntu. Not sure what is wrong!

Nothing present in the apache logs or system logs. I can't find a specific error or error that would be of relation.

Comment: hi, not sure if this might be of interest https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/issues/890 https://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2014-12/0103.shtml

Comment: Oh boy, that's complicated! There is no client or load, it's a non production environment. I saw that sometimes the kernel can be to blame and updates to the kernel have fixed similar issues in the past. Not sure at this point if it is kernel, apache, or system related, or something thereof. It could be related, I might try a kernel downgrade before I get too deep.